# Symfony Page Not Found

Tags: php, symfony

I installed a ready-made php script on my server written with the Symfony library. When I look at the route file, everything looks normal. I give an example:

```
   app_home_index:
      path:     /admin/
      defaults: { _controller: AppBundle:Home:index }
```

but when I go to http://example.com/admin/ I get a page not found error. Is there anyone who can help?

Comment: i hope this is formatting, but there are too many spaces all around. double-check with `bin/console debug:router`

Comment: @Jakumi While showing the example, the space is wrong, actually there is no space there.

Comment: what does `bin/console debug:router` output?

Comment: I am not familiar with symfony. I do not fully understand what you are talking about. What should I do?

Comment: usually, people follow one of the tutorials online. mainly the one on symfony.com where you download the symfony command line tool `symfony` and create a project. this will also create a folder `bin` in the project dir, containing the `console` script, which can be called from the project root via `bin/console debug:router` or on some systems (mostly windows) `php bin/console debug:router`, which should output all defined routes.

Comment: Please share more details, like the **exact** content of that routing file. Have you checked whether it is even parsed?

Comment: https://hastebin.com/sozeripade.yaml

Comment: the script is not installed in my localhost, I installed it on the host. It did not work due to errors caused by the php version or the mysql version in my localhost. I installed it on the host, it works on the host now. I can give an FTP to someone who can help.